# Domain of a legend in D3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am a beginner in D3 charts and working to pick it up fast.
I was working on a heatmap chart with legend, which looks perfect at the moment. As I have hard-coded the domain values in legend, what will happen when the domain changes, or its dynamic?
How can we link the domain in a d3 chart to a variable dataset?

Comment: Domain means minimum and maximum value of the data provided by you ? you can use `d3.scale.linear().domain([0,10000])` to pass the hard coded values

Comment: You question is not so clear. please edit it and post some code so that we can provide better answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `scale` functions of d3 to map minimum/maximum bounds to domains/ranges:

[Setting Scales Domains and Ranges in d3.js](http://www.d3noob.org/2012/12/setting-scales-domains-and-ranges-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

d3js uses scales to manipulate data.

```
var xScale = d3.scale.linear(); // defining scale

xScale.domain([minVal, maxVal]) //minVal & max are  minimum value of your data

xScale.range([0, 100]) // actual svg width that you want to assign to your domain
```

and if you are changing data then you have to change domain of your scale and redraw the graph.